# Read collection in Firestore to get GEO data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read a collection group in Firestore to get the GEO data. My path looks like this. How do I get all documents and thus all GEO data that are in "Houses" collection?

Activity:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Houses")
val geoFire = GeoFire(ref)

val geoQuery: GeoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(37.7832, -122.4056), 0.6)
```

Path in Firestore:

> /User/emails@provider.com/Houses/randomDoc

[image]

Comment: Aside from my answer, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code creates a reference that points to the `Houses` node in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database):

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Houses")
```

On the other hand, your screenshot shows a [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) database. While both databases are a part of Firebase products, both are different databases with different mechanisms. So to create a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) that points to the `Houses` sub-collection, you have to use the following lines of code:

```
val email = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.email
val db = Firebase.firestore
val housesRef = db.collection("User").document(email).collection("Houses")
housesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { /* ... /* }
```